# Products dropdown in SO Top Bar is independent from other dropdowns

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, top-bar

All other dropdowns in the top bar are somehow implemented the same way, sharing their style and allowing only one of them to be open at the same time. Products, however, does not only look different, but can also be opened in parallel to other menus.

[image]

This should probably be changed to use the same look and feel as well as technology, to create a cohesive user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Our products dropdown is powered by a component from our [design system](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/popovers). The others are considered legacy and may eventually be updated to the new component if there’s a refactor, or a feature needs the new component (generally, whichever comes first). It's not ideal that those two menus show at the same time—I can look into fixing that—but we likely won’t be touching those legacy dropdown menus soon.

Comment: FWIW, stylistically, I much prefer the "legacy" dropdowns and it would be disappointing to see them changed to look like the new products dropdown at any point in the future